# Metal/Metal2 + Swift: How to pass complex Swift structure as shader argument?

Tags: swift, metal

I have a struct in Metal:

```
struct BlurDesc {
    short fenceRows;
    short offs;
    short sampleCnt;
    float muls[64];
};
```

It is used as a shader argument:

```
kernel void hBlurCompute(
    constant BlurDesc & blurDesc [[ buffer(0) ]],
    texture2d<half, access::read> srcTexture [[ texture(0) ]],
    texture2d<half, access::write> hBlurTexture [[ texture(1) ]],
    ushort gid [[ thread_position_in_grid ]]
) {
```

Here is the corresponding Swift struct:

```
struct BlurDesc {
    var fenceRows : Int16 = 0
    var offs : Int16 = -32
    var sampleCnt : Int16 = 64
    let muls = Array<Float>(repeating: (1.0/64), count: 64)
}

var blurDesc = BlurDesc()
```

How can I pass the Swift struct to the shader as argument?

Is it possible to create a byte buffer from it with the right byte order and pass it to: *MTLDevice.makeBuffer(bytes pointer: UnsafeRawPointer, length: Int, options: MTLResourceOptions = [])* somehow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(Unless they've recently added something to the language definition), Swift does not guarantee the memory layout of structs in raw memory, either the byte order, element order, any padding, or even whether a struct is contiguous (and not broken up into non-adjacent sub-blocks).

So the most robust solution purely in Swift (and not just the one that works with the current version of the compilers you are testing) is to use (unsafe)raw(buffer)pointers, and manually pack bytes into the Metal buffers.

Or just use a C struct and C subroutines to pack it (all callable from Swift using a bridging header).

Comment: Here's someone's github project to help with the packing : https://github.com/michaeldorner/ByteBackpacker

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to go forward.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use the Apple simd framework to avoid pain.

`swift`

```
struct BlurDesc {
    var fenceRows : simd_short1 = 0
    var offs : simd_short1 = -32
    var sampleCnt : simd_short1 = 64
    let muls = Array<simd_float>(repeating: (1.0/64), count: 64)
}
```